# Postgresql. Create function get_ticket

Tags: postgresql, sql-function

1. Create a function to Get Ticket (for a Reservation).Ticket a booked reservation when the passenger pays the total amount.
2. Create a trigger, called line disruption, that adjusts all the tickets to the immediate next line when a line is closed due to an accident or maintenance, unless the customer specified no substitutions/adjustments in which case the ticket is canceled.

I created the tables, but I have some mistakes on my function: Please show me the mistakes and explain your solutions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ticket (reservation_id int, id int, price int) 
RETURNS SETOF ticket 
AS $$ 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO Ticket (ticket_id, reservation_id, price); 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE Customer (
  id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  fname varchar, 
  lname varchar, 
  street varchar, 
  town varchar, 
  postal_code varchar
);

CREATE TABLE Station (
  id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  name varchar, 
  open_time varchar, 
  close_time varchar, 
  stop_delay int, 
  street varchar, 
  town varchar, 
  postal_code varchar
);

CREATE TABLE Train ( 
  id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  name varchar, 
  description varchar, 
  seat_avail int, 
  top_speed int, 
  cost_per_km int
);

CREATE TABLE Rail_Line (
  line_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  speed_limit int
);

CREATE TABLE Passes_Thru_SRL (
  line_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  station_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  distance int, 
  CONSTRAINT FK1_SRL FOREIGN KEY (line_id) REFERENCES Rail_Line (line_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK2_SRL FOREIGN KEY (station_id) REFERENCES Station (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Route ( 
  route_id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Passes_Thru_SR (
  route_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  station_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  stops bool, 
  CONSTRAINT FK1_SR FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES Route (route_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK2_SR FOREIGN KEY (station_id) REFERENCES Station (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Route_Schedule (
  route_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  day varchar, 
  time varchar, 
  train_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  CONSTRAINT FK1_RS FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES Route (route_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK2_RS FOREIGN KEY (train_id) REFERENCES Train (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Reservation (
  reservation_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  price int PRIMARY KEY, 
  id int, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_RS FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Customer (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Ticket (
  ticket_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  reservation_id int, 
  id int, price int, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_RS1 FOREIGN KEY (reservation_id) REFERENCES Reservation (reservation_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_RS2 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Customer (id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT FK_RS3 FOREIGN KEY (price) REFERENCES Reservation (price) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: You need to go here [Pg formatter](https://sqlformat.darold.net/) and format the function and table definitions. Then go here [Code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **Code Blocks** and see how '```' are used to format code. Then apply to above to make it readable.

Comment: Take a pen and a sheet of paper and draw a diagram for yourself - e.g. when the customer approaches the booth and asks for a ticket - there might be no more tickets left. So draw what happens next if there are tickets - and if there are not. Then explain what a `line` is and what can happen to it. Then continue with the diagram. It will help you solve the problem - first in your head, and **only then** in your code.

Comment: Your tables have issues. A table can only have **one** primary key. You are trying to create tables with more than one PK. A primary key can however consist of more than one column. But the syntax for that is different. A FK column must exist in the table, so you can't make the non-existing `price` column in the `ticket` table a foreign key but defining a column `price` as a primary or foreign key seems questionable to begin with.

Comment: Besides the other issues already mentioned I see 1) No trigger in your code 2) The procedure in the function you show could be done as just an INSERT without a function. I second the suggestion from  @IVOGELOV, sketch out the flow of what you want first.